# Why the content of p tag is nothing but it has a length is 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a segment of HTML code as below

```
<div id="test">
  <img width="570" title="20160201121020_208.png" src="/201602/01/20160201121020_208.png" hasele="">
  <p>&#8203;&nbsp;</p>
  <p>


  </p>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript code follows below

```
$("#test").children().each(function(idx, p){
    node = $(p);

    if(node.is("div") || node.is("p")){
        var txt = $.trim(node.text());
        if(txt != ""){
            console.log("========="+ txt + ":" + txt.length);
        }
    }
});
```

The result of console.log is "=========1", which made me confused. Because I thought console.log should have not a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `p` elements:

1. One containing a zero-width space character and a non-breaking ("hard") space character
2. Another containing various spaces and/or line breaks

[`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim) will trim the latter, but will only remove the hard space (not the zero-width space) from the first one. If you want to remove that zero-width space, you have to do so specifically. (JavaScript's own `String#trim` [[spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.trim) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)] will also leave the zero-width space behind.)

```
var txt = node.text().replace(/[\s\u200B]/g, '');
```

`\u200B` is the Unicode escape for that `&#8203;` HTML character entity.

**Live Example:**

```js
$("#test").children().each(function(idx, p){
    node = $(p);

    if(node.is("div") || node.is("p")){
        var txt = node.text().replace(/[\s\u200B]/g, '');
        if(txt != ""){
            console.log("========="+ txt + ":" + txt.length);
        } else {
            console.log("It's blank");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <img width="570" title="20160201121020_208.png" src="/201602/01/20160201121020_208.png" hasele="">
    <p>&#8203;&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
  
  
    </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```